# meaning of numbers in the proguard mapping

Tags: android, proguard, android-r8

I can see that the following lines are present in the proguard mapping that got generated after building my application:

```
1000:1000:void onCreate(android.os.Bundle):44 -> onCreate
2000:2000:void onClick(android.view.View):101 -> onClick
3000:3000:void onClick(android.view.View):104 -> onClick
```

In the above mapping, 1000:1000 signifies the line number of that method. What does ":44", ":101" or ":104" mean here?

I couldn't find any documentation on the same. Is there a documentation where I can find the meaning of all the sections present inside the proguard mapping.

Comment: Looks like :44, :101 etc are line numbers of the file where the corresponding methods appear

Comment: `In the above mapping, 1000:1000 signifies the line number of that method. ` where did you read that?

Comment: Did you find answer what numbers means ?